# Proving inequality too simple?

Tags: inequality

If I would like to show that $\exists y \in R, \ \forall x \in R:(y-x)^2-6(y-x)>9$, does it make sense to say:

Consider $x \in R$. Let $y=x$ thus $y \in R$, and show that $9>0$?

Or, would I need to find a more specific value of $y$? It just seems too straight forward.

Comment: You need a fixed value of $y$, so that for all $x$, the equality is true. *$y$ must not depend on $x$.*

Comment: Okay - so I need to find one exact value of y to show this is true (or not if I can't find a value of y). And, y cannot have x in it in any form? Such as, I cannot write y=x+1, or any such thing?

Comment: Right, so one exact value does the job, which is fixed for all $x$, like $y=77$  or $y=25,647$, but should not depend on $x$ in any way.

Answer (score 3):

You want to prove that there exists a $y$ such that for all $x$ it follows that $0<(y-x)^2-6(y-x)+9 = (y-x-3)^2.$ Note that this inequality holds if and only if $y-x\neq 3$.  However for any $y$, taking $x=  y-3$ yields precisely that $(y-x-3)^2=0$, contradicting your statement.  It seems what you have written is not true.

Comment: Thank-you for catching that, back to the drawing board.